# Team Foundation Server MSSCCI Provider slowness issue

Tags: tfs, plsqldeveloper, msscci

I've installed Team Foundation Server MSSCCI Provider 2010 and use it to connect Oracle PL/SQL developer (ver 7.1.5) to TFS 2010.

now the problem is that the operations that require TFS (check-in, check-out,..., etc) is very slow and causing the PL/SQL environment to hang for a while (in some cases it hangs for more that 5 minutes).

My question is that is this a known issue for MSSCCI? and what I can do to overcome the slowness problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please ask this question on the msdn forum http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsversioncontrol as the developers working on msscci are actively monitoring it. Afaik, Oracle Pl/SQL was not tested with msscci provider so this would be a new issue. The most probable issue is that Oracle Developer is quering file status very frequently, which hits the server every time, you can confirm it using tracing (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michalma/archive/2006/12/08/tracing-in-tfs-msscci-provider.aspx)